# Tomcat 7 ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.tomcat.JarScanner

Tags: java, unix, tomcat, tomcat7

When I try and start my app I get this error. I have verified that JarScanner exists in the CATALINA_HOME directory so I dont know why it cant find it. Is there anything that could lead to this issue starting my app?

```
Oct 8, 2012 1:24:01 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase addChildInternal
SEVERE: ContainerBase.addChild: start: 
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/client]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:618)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:650)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDescriptor.run(HostConfig.java:1582)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:441)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/tomcat/JarScanner
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:631)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:615)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:141)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:283)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(URLClassLoader.java:58)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:197)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:295)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.getJarScanner(StandardContext.java:1025)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processJarsForWebFragments(ContextConfig.java:1911)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.webConfig(ContextConfig.java:1265)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:878)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:369)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5173)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 11 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.tomcat.JarScanner
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
    ... 33 more
Oct 8, 2012 1:24:01 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDescriptor
SEVERE: Error deploying configuration descriptor /software/sirsi/tomcat_sbox7/conf/Catalina/localhost/client.xml
java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/client]]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:904)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:618)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:650)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDescriptor.run(HostConfig.java:1582)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:441)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Oct 8, 2012 1:24:01 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDescriptor
INFO: Deploying configuration descriptor /software/sirsi/tomcat_sbox7/conf/Catalina/localhost/custom.xml
Oct 8, 2012 1:24:01 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext setPath
WARNING: A context path must either be an empty string or start with a '/'. The path [custom] does not meet these criteria and has been changed to [/custom]
Oct 8, 2012 1:24:01 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.SetContextPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetContextPropertiesRule]{Context} Setting property 'debug' to '0' did not find a matching property.
Oct 8, 2012 1:24:01 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase addChildInternal
SEVERE: ContainerBase.addChild: start: 
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/custom]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:618)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:650)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDescriptor.run(HostConfig.java:1582)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:441)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/tomcat/util/scan/StandardJarScanner
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.getJarScanner(StandardContext.java:1025)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processJarsForWebFragments(ContextConfig.java:1911)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.webConfig(ContextConfig.java:1265)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:878)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:369)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5173)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 11 more
Oct 8, 2012 1:24:01 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDescriptor
SEVERE: Error deploying configuration descriptor /software/sirsi/tomcat_sbox7/conf/Catalina/localhost/custom.xml
java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/custom]]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:904)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:618)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:650)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDescriptor.run(HostConfig.java:1582)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:441)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    at     java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

Comment: offtopic; belongs on serverfault.

Answer (score -2):

The jar file needs to be on the classpath (not in CATALINA_HOME).

Comment: Well in the catalina.properties file for my app (CATALINA_BASE) I have common.loader=${catalina.home}/lib/*.jar which seems to find all the other jars in CATALINA_HOME. This fixed an issue I was having earlier where tomcat couldn't find the Catalina class.

Comment: My answer's wrong as it stands - JarScanner is part of Tomcat. Do you have a JarScanner.jar file in Tomcat's root directory? Did you move it there?

Comment: No, I have found that the JarScanner class is part of the tomcat-api.jar which is in the lib directory. I also found this towards the beginning of the same log that gives the error:[Loaded org.apache.tomcat.JarScanner from file:/usr/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.30/lib/tomcat-api.jar]

Comment: "I have common.loader=${catalina.home}/lib/*.jar which seems to find all the other jars in CATALINA_HOME" -  do you mean in CATALINA_HOME/lib?

Comment: You should have something like this: common.loader=${catalina.home}/lib,${catalina.home}/lib/*.jar in conf/catalina.properties. I wouldn't change this (or override it)

Comment: I changed the commonloader to what you said but the error hasn't changed.

Answer (score -3):

Put your jar in your webapps folder follow steps

1.Go to programfiles>Apache Software Foundation>Tomcat >
Webapps.

1. put you jar in (your directory created)/WEB-INF /lib directory

then run on localhost to execute it.

Comment: This is a unix system, and also please see the answer below.