# In eclipse start tomcat error

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat

Relevant configuration: 
Fedora and 
Tomcat 7.0.35 < opened with a browser start page display blank > 
Eclipse the latest edition 
Firefox 17 
jdk 1.7
javaee5

In the fedora with tomcat (with terminal can start, open the browser to see is a blank page), with the eclipse start error:

Error is as follows:

```
February 16, 2013 in the afternoon. 4:45:01 org apache. Catalina. Core. AprLifecycleListener init

INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on The Java. Library. Path: / usr/Java/jdk1.7.0 _13 / jre/lib/i386 / client: / usr/Java/jdk1.7.0 _13 / jre/lib/i386: : / usr/Java/packages/lib/i386: / lib/usr/lib

February 16, 2013 in the afternoon. 4:45:01 org apache. Tomcat. Util. Digester. SetPropertiesRule begin

WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule] {Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org. Eclipse. JST. Jee. Server: Test' did not find a matching property.

February 16, 2013 in the afternoon. 4:45:01 org apache. Coyote. AbstractProtocol init

INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler [" HTTP - bio - 9090 "]

February 16, 2013 in the afternoon. 4:45:01 org apache. Coyote. AbstractProtocol init

INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler [" ajp - bio - 9009 "]

February 16, 2013 in the afternoon. 4:45:01 org apache. Catalina. Startup. Catalina load

INFO: Initialization processed in 1051 ms

February 16, 2013 in the afternoon. 4:45:01 org apache. Catalina. Core. StandardService startInternal

INFO: Starting service Catalina

February 16, 2013 in the afternoon. 4:45:01 org apache. Catalina. Core. StandardEngine startInternal

INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat / 7.0.35

February 16, 2013 in the afternoon. 4:45:01 org apache. Catalina. Core. ContainerBase startInternal

SEVERE: A child container failed during start



java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[]]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerGet(FutureTask.java:252)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:111)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1123)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:800)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[]]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
        ... 7 more



Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/tomcat/JarScanner
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:791)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:410)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:30
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:410)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.getJarScanner(StandardContext.java:1031)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processJarsForWebFragments(ContextConfig.java:1915)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.webConfig(ContextConfig.java:126
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:87
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:369)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:119)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5179)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        ... 7 more


Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.tomcat.JarScanner
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
        ... 30 more



February 16, 2013 in the afternoon. 4:45:01 org apache. Catalina. Core. ContainerBase startInternal

SEVERE: A child container failed during start



java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/Test]]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerGet(FutureTask.java:252)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:111)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1123)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:800)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/Test]]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
        ... 7 more


Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/tomcat/util/scan/StandardJarScanner
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.getJarScanner(StandardContext.java:1031)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processJarsForWebFragments(ContextConfig.java:1915)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.webConfig(ContextConfig.java:126
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:87
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:369)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:119)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5179)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        ... 7 more





    February 16, 2013 in the afternoon. 4:45:01 org apache. Catalina. Core. ContainerBase startInternal

    SEVERE: A child container failed during start

    Java. Util. Concurrent. ExecutionException: apache. Org. Catalina. LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine [catalina]. StandardHost [localhost]]

    At Java. Util. Concurrent. FutureTask $Sync. InnerGet (FutureTask. Java: 252)

    At Java. Util. Concurrent. FutureTask. Get (FutureTask. Java: 111)

    At org. Apache. Catalina. Core. ContainerBase. StartInternal (ContainerBase. Java: 1123)

    At org. Apache. Catalina. Core. StandardEngine. StartInternal (StandardEngine. Java: 302)

    At org. Apache. Catalina. Util. LifecycleBase. Start (LifecycleBase. Java: 150)

    At org. Apache. Catalina. Core. StandardService. StartInternal (StandardService. Java: 443)

    At org. Apache. Catalina. Util. LifecycleBase. Start (LifecycleBase. Java: 150)

    At org. Apache. Catalina. Core. StandardServer. StartInternal (StandardServer. Java: 732)

    At org. Apache. Catalina. Util. LifecycleBase. Start (LifecycleBase. Java: 150)

    At org. Apache. Catalina. Startup. Catalina. Start (catalina. Java: 684)

    At sun. NativeMethodAccessorImpl reflect. Invoke0 (Native Method).

    At sun. Reflect. NativeMethodAccessorImpl. Invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl. Java: 57)

    At sun. Reflect. DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl. Invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl. Java: 43)

    At Java. Lang. Reflect. Invoke Method. (Method. Java: 601)

    At org. Apache. Catalina. Startup. Bootstrap. Start (Bootstrap. Java: 322)

    At org. Apache. Catalina. Startup. Bootstrap. Main (Bootstrap. Java: 456)

    Caused by: apache. Org. Catalina. LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine [catalina]. StandardHost [localhost]]

    At org. Apache. Catalina. Util. LifecycleBase. Start (LifecycleBase. Java: 154)

    At org. Apache. Catalina. Core. ContainerBase $StartChild. Call (ContainerBase. Java: 1559)

    At org. Apache. Catalina. Core. ContainerBase $StartChild. Call (ContainerBase. Java: 1549)

    At Java. Util. Concurrent. FutureTask $Sync. InnerRun (FutureTask. Java: 334)

    At Java. Util. Concurrent. FutureTask. Run (FutureTask. Java: 166)

    At Java. Util. Concurrent. ThreadPoolExecutor. RunWorker (ThreadPoolExecutor. Java: 1145)

    At Java. Util. Concurrent. ThreadPoolExecutor $Worker. Run (ThreadPoolExecutor. Java: 615)

    At Java. Lang. Thread. Run (Thread. Java: 722)

    Caused by: apache. Org. Catalina. LifecycleException: A child container failed during start

    At org. Apache. Catalina. Core. ContainerBase. StartInternal (ContainerBase. Java: 1131)

    At org. Apache. Catalina. Core. StandardHost. StartInternal (StandardHost. Java: 800)

    At org. Apache. Catalina. Util. LifecycleBase. Start (LifecycleBase. Java: 150)

    ... 7 more






  February 16, 2013 in the afternoon. 4:45:01 org apache. Catalina. Startup. Catalina start

    SEVERE: Catalina. Start:

    Org. Apache. Catalina. LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardServer [9005]]

    At org. Apache. Catalina. Util. LifecycleBase. Start (LifecycleBase. Java: 154)

    At org. Apache. Catalina. Startup. Catalina. Start (catalina. Java: 684)

    At sun. NativeMethodAccessorImpl reflect. Invoke0 (Native Method).

    At sun. Reflect. NativeMethodAccessorImpl. Invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl. Java: 57)

    At sun. Reflect. DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl. Invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl. Java: 43)

    At Java. Lang. Reflect. Invoke Method. (Method. Java: 601)

    At org. Apache. Catalina. Startup. Bootstrap. Start (Bootstrap. Java: 322)

    At org. Apache. Catalina. Startup. Bootstrap. Main (Bootstrap. Java: 456)

    Caused by: apache. Org. Catalina. LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardService [catalina]]

    At org. Apache. Catalina. Util. LifecycleBase. Start (LifecycleBase. Java: 154)

    At org. Apache. Catalina. Core. StandardServer. StartInternal (StandardServer. Java: 732)

    At org. Apache. Catalina. Util. LifecycleBase. Start (LifecycleBase. Java: 150)

    ... 7 more

    Caused by: apache. Org. Catalina. LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine [catalina]]

    At org. Apache. Catalina. Util. LifecycleBase. Start (LifecycleBase. Java: 154)

    At org. Apache. Catalina. Core. StandardService. StartInternal (StandardService. Java: 443)

    At org. Apache. Catalina. Util. LifecycleBase. Start (LifecycleBase. Java: 150)

    ... And more

    Caused by: apache. Org. Catalina. LifecycleException: A child container failed during start

    At org. Apache. Catalina. Core. ContainerBase. StartInternal (ContainerBase. Java: 1131)

    At org. Apache. Catalina. Core. StandardEngine. StartInternal (StandardEngine. Java: 302)

    At org. Apache. Catalina. Util. LifecycleBase. Start (LifecycleBase. Java: 150)

    ... 11 more

    February 16, 2013 in the afternoon. 4:45:01 org apache. Catalina. Startup. Catalina start

    INFO: Server startup in 279 ms
```

I am looking at tutorial self-study, excuse me with myeclipse can learn JSP?

JDK is just install jdk1.7, originally in the ext (put the third party jar bag inside the). Put a lot of tomcat bag, then copy to the JDK client folder inside or not

Comment: `Caused by: Java. Lang. NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/tomcat/JarScanner`

Comment: Possible duplicate:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12787277/tomcat-7-classnotfoundexception-org-apache-tomcat-jarscanner

Comment: Where processing? JDK? Still?

Comment: I used the fedora yum install tomcat after installation, Eclipse can't identify version (I mixed up tomcat's root directory)?

Comment: Did you check about the missing class?

Comment: Check, still prompt error

Comment: Check your classpath for the missing classes